# Docusign redirection

Tags: angularjs, iframe, docusignapi

I'm building an integration between my application and Docusign. This is flow:

1. Log in to Docusign with credentials. OK
2. Getting envelope from Docusign. OK
3. Getting Recipient View URL. OK
4. Open  with received URL. OK
5. User signs/declines document. OK
6. Redirect to given URL. (when I build request I have set up a return URL)

I'm using API call : Recipientv2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/views/recipient (http://iodocs.docusign.com/#)

Everything is fine except step 6.

When using this flow in my application I get this error in FF:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
http://localhost:8080/#/land/10000?event=decline does not permit
framing.
```

In Chrome I get:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/#/land/10001?event=decline'
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I'm using tomcat, spring, angularJs, ....

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: When posting DocuSign questions on Stack Overflow, if they are development/technical/api related then please use the DocuSignAPI tag, not the generic DocuSign tag (which is reserved for more general questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into is not related to DocuSign at all - the page you are trying to display in an iFrame is set to not allow displaying in iFrame.

You need to set the `X-Frame-Options` header on the localhost page you are trying to re-direct to:

```
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN, GOFORIT
```

Comment: Also, this is pretty much a dup of other SO questions like this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767901/1968395